# Geforce GT 540M on HDMI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a First FSM-270 2560x1440 monitor that I can seem to get to work. My laptop has is an ASUS with GT 540M graphics card, I am not sure but it only seems to drive the VGA output. There is a HDMI output but seems to be controlled by Intel HD Graphics 3000 card that is only good for 1920x1080 and wont run the monitor.

The monitor has a DVI-D input and I have a DVI-D to HDMI cable.

Is it possible to set things up for the GT 540M to run the new monitor from the HDMI output?